# Figuring out MongoDB database Model and References

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am trying to figure out the ideal design for my MongoDB model that I will be using in my NodeJS app. The app is set up like a survey, with certain steps providing options based on the previous selections. Here is an example of the selections and possibilities.

Level 1: Type of pattern: solid, stripe, plaid
Level 2 (Same options regardless of level 1 selection): Color: Grey, Blue, Green, Red
Results: Images are displayed based on the level 1 and level 2 selection.

Based on this structure, the only element to the database are the images that are displayed based on the two levels of selections. Based on this idea, how many collections should I be making and what would be the best primary key to tie together references between level 1, level 2, results, to display the right images?

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid multiple collections for modelling this scenario because MongoDB does not support joins and as you say you will want to tie together references between level 1 and level 2. It also sounds like a document representing one image will be fairly small and simple - if there was a possibility of an image having very many colors, it might not be appropriate to model an image in one document. So I would go for one collection with each document modelling one image.

It sounds like your images have two properties, color and pattern.

A simple schema if each image only has 1 color and 1 pattern would be:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('...'),
    name: "image1",
    color: "green",
    pattern: "solid"
}
```

A schema that allows each image to have multiple colors and patterns would be:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('...'),
    name: "image1",
    color: ["green", "red"],
    pattern: ["plaid", "solid"]
}
```

You could query either of the above schemas using a query like this:

```
db.images.find({ pattern:"solid", color: "green" });
```

Using [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) (MongoDB object modelling library for Node), the first schema would look something like the following. Note the use of `enum` in the application code to limit these fields to valid values.

```
var imageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    color: { type: String, enum: ['grey', 'blue', 'green', 'red'] },
    pattern: { type: String, enum: ['solid', 'stripe', 'plaid'] },
    name: String,
});
var Image = mongoose.model('image', imageSchema, 'images');

Image.find({ pattern:"solid", color: "green" }).exec(callback);
```